# Is it correct "Accepting payments was never this simple and easy"

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, sentence

Is it correct to say *Accepting payments was never this simple and easy* -- I am concerned about the plural + *was*; is that correct?

Comment: The subject is not _payments_ but _accepting_ which is singular.

When acting as subjects of a sentence, gerunds and infinitives are _always singular_ and require singular verbs.

Comment: _Simple_ and _easy_ are straight synonyms in this context. You might want to use just one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

> Accepting payments was never this simple and easy.

The subject of the verb *was* is not *payments*, but the verbal *accepting*, which is singular. Commonly called a [*gerund*](https://www.thoughtco.com/gerund-in-grammar-1690897) — the *-ing* form of a verb functioning as a noun phrase — a verbal such as *accepting* can still take complements like *payments* or be modified by adverbs just as any verb:

> [*Conveniently accepting payments*](https://www.ecsuite.com/merchant-account-solutions) is a big part of any successful business... — Merchant Account Solutions

When the *-ing* form of the verb takes a plural and can be modified by adjectives, then it is no longer a verbal, but a [deverbal noun](https://www.thoughtco.com/deverbal-grammar-term-1690384) that functions as any other noun:

> They reflect the investors' view that [*the then current earnings*](https://books.google.de/books?id=4b9FAQAAIAAJ&q=%22High+earnings+are%22&dq=%22High+earnings+are%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD8cjmzYfcAhXCT8AKHXMeAf8Q6AEIVTAI) were only temporarily low and that they would improve as economic conditions returned to normal. In the usual case, abnormally high earnings are viewed with skepticism… — Alan E. Grunewald, *Stock Valuation in Federal Taxation*, 1961, 85.

The remarkable thing about gerunds is that if two or more are joined by a coordinating conjunction in the subject of a clause, they still take a singular verb if considered a single action, task, or state:

[image]

[*Source*](https://flybluekite.com/importance-of-gratitude/)

Despite its plural construction, *Feeling gratitude and not expressing it* describes a single state, thus takes a singular verb. How a writer wishes to depict an action/state, as single or separate, determines whether the verb is singular or plural:

> [*Washing and ironing*](https://books.google.de/books?id=_WXsAAAAMAAJ&q=%22washing+and+ironing+a+shirt+costs%22&dq=%22washing+and+ironing+a+shirt+costs%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi24a3vuofcAhWF26QKHS__BHAQ6AEIJDAA) a shirt ***costs*** US$1.10. — *La Ruta Maya, Yucatán, Guatemala & Belize: A Travel Survival Kit*, 1991.
>
> [*Washing and ironing **were***](https://books.google.de/books?id=vU_aAAAAMAAJ&q=%22washing+and+ironing%22&dq=%22washing+and+ironing%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfmOattofcAhUisKQKHfa5CYY4ChDoAQguMAM) hard, hot work, done under cramped conditions.  — Nancy F. Cott, *Domestic Ideology and Domestic Work*, Part 2, 1992, 348.
>
> Unless you are exceedingly lucky, [*starting and running a small business **is***](https://books.google.de/books?id=Kz0vAAAAYAAJ&q=%22starting+and+running+a+small+business+is%22&dq=%22starting+and+running+a+small+business+is%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi484X6wofcAhXEyqQKHYPUC7IQ6AEIPzAF) a very time-consuming and emotionally draining process. — *U.S. News & World Report*, 91 (1981), 75.
>
> [*Starting a small business and running it*](https://www.bdc.ca/en/articles-tools/start-buy-business/start-business/pages/7-keys-starting-small-business.aspx) successfully ***are*** no easy tasks. — Business Development Bank of Canada.

And no matter how many gerunds or how many objects, if the task itself is seen as one activity, then the verb is still singular:

> 02.01.2018 · [*Cleaning and maintaining swimming pools, spas, fountains, artificial waterfalls or koi ponds **is***](https://www.goldcoastpoolandspa.com/2018/01/02/critical-pool-fountain-water-feature-maintenance/) hard work and requires following specific rules… — Gold Coast Pool & Spa.